# Microsoft Windows Mobile Remote Debugging API

Tags: windows-mobile, remote-debugging, corecon

Visual Studio comes with a set of "Remote Tools" (like Remote Spy, Zoom-In, Process Viewer, etc...) for debugging applications on Windows Mobile and Windows CE devices. These applications will work either a USB ActiveSync connection or over a TCP/IP network with [Remote Debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228708%28VS.80%29.aspx) enabled on the device. The RAPI and RAPI2 interfaces, however, will only connect to devices over ActiveSync.

What are these "Remote Tools" applications using that allows them to connect over any TCP/IP network? Is there some API other than RAPI & RAPI2 that allows this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The remote tools are using the [CoreCon APIs](http://blogs.msdn.com/vsdteam/archive/tags/connectivity/default.aspx), not RAPI.